# Sound not working on AU114TX

Tags: drivers, speakers

How to fix it? I have B&O built in speakers. This is the Pavilion series. Earlier it was working fine, but all of a sudden, it stopped working. This has happened this time **again** after I formatted my PC. So formatting isn't an option I deduce from it.

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal and run `pavucontrol` (should be preinstalled). There you will find the connected sound devices and you can change the active ones. It is very likely that the wrong device is selected. That works for me whenever my set-up changes (for example after removing the hdmi cable and the corresponding sound device).
If for a reason this doesn't work, try if you can change settings in the `alsamixer`

Comment: Thanks! I will continue using my PC for some days and accept your answer if it turns out all good!